# Android 10 No Network Traffic - Google Play Console Pre-launch Report

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-10.0

I'm not seeing network traffic on my apps when running on Google's test environment.  Here is a picture showing the zero bytes transferred compared to other Android versions.  The problem is limited to Android 10 and other versions are able to send and receive data.

I'm thinking I'm missing something in the app that prevents network traffic on version 10 but I see no errors or indications of problems.

Has anyone seen this or know of a solution?

[image]